# Set typeface for listview

Tags: android, listview, fonts, typeface

i tried to set typeface for text view with this method:

```
public static final void setAppFont(ViewGroup mContainer, Typeface mFont)
{
    if (mContainer == null || mFont == null) return;

    final int mCount = mContainer.getChildCount();

    // Loop through all of the children.
    for (int i = 0; i < mCount; ++i)
    {
        final View mChild = mContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (mChild instanceof TextView)
        {
            // Set the font if it is a TextView.
            ((TextView) mChild).setTypeface(mFont);
        }
        else if (mChild instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            // Recursively attempt another ViewGroup.
            setAppFont((ViewGroup) mChild, mFont);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // See assets/res/any/layout/styled_text.xml for this
    // view layout definition.
    setContentView(R.layout.read_asset);


    final Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "myfont.otf"); 
            final ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(
            android.R.id.content).getRootView();
            MyActivity.setAppFont(mContainer, mFont);
}
```

but now i want to set the same typeface for this listview adapter:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;



// ArrayList for Listview

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listview Data


String products[] = {"item1", "item2","item3","item4","item5","item6" };



    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
}
```

Are there any suggestions? 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Just override the `getView` method of your adapter:

```
    final Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.otf"); 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if(convertView == null) MyActivity.setAppFont(view, mFont);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Note that you should call `createFromAsset()` once, outside of `getView()`, so you do not have to go through all that I/O on each `getView()` call. Also, you really only need to call `setAppFont()` if `contentView` is `null` and hence the superclass had to create a new layout -- otherwise, it should already have the right font.

Comment: Thank you  CommonsWare.  i tried your suggestion but i still have the same font.

Comment: I'm having an error `Cannot resolve method setAppFont()`, what should I do about it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
I suggest you to use a custom list adapter which helps you in adding or customizing your list view as you need.

for example In the getView() method you can do like this

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
View convertView = arg1;

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                 inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflating, arg2, false);
            TextView mTV_names = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.inflating_TV_names);

            // typeface used to display the text in different language other than english 
            // here it is tamil, hindi and telugu.

            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");

            //setting the typeface to the particular text 

            mTV_names.setTypeface(face);
            mTV_names.setText(""+countries[arg0]);
            return convertView;

        }
    }
```

once have a look at [check this](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/localization-using-ttf-files.html)

if you need to use the function that you are trying to use instead of writing all the stuff just call the `setAppFont(convertView, face)` from the getView() method

Comment: thank you for the response . i really don't know how to deal with this case . because data in list view are added this way: String products[] = {"item1", "item2","item3","item4","item5","item6" };

Comment: I added a link at the bottom which may help you. Have a look at that

Comment: And as  CommonsWare suggested call the createFromAsset outside the function to avoid it called every now and then.